# Can WebView be used for HTML parsing?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I came across the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) class in android.webkit and was impressed by how it "does everything for you" (as a programmer), as far as rendering visual HTTP content on the screen.

My question: Is it possible to use the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) class as a shortcut for parsing rendered HTML for **non-visual** purposes?

(that is, retrieve certain elements from a web page for text processing, etc.)

If so, how would one go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to, as far as I know, Android is using [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to parse HTML, and you can use it too.

Comment: TagSoup looks like a better solution than WebView. Thank you very much!  Do you know how TagSoup compares (or relates) to http://jsoup.org/ ?

Comment: How can you use TagSoup from the Android API?

Comment: @Patrick, it's not part of the API, you need to reference it (and ship) with your application

Comment: this is too bad because TagSoup is used internally by the API, see [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)